# zsh: correct 'puts' to 'tput'

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, zsh, ruby-1.9.2

I have rvm and ruby version 1.9.2 installed. I have Mac OS X 10.7. Why is puts not getting recognized?
puts ('Hello Ruby')
zsh: correct 'puts' to 'tput' [nyae]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you want to enter the Ruby code directly at a shell prompt, which won't work. Try `ruby -e "puts('Hello Ruby')"` and then start to learn how to write actual Ruby programs, e.g. with Chris Pine's "Learn to Program":

http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/

Comment: Oh Thanks! Just started to learn ruby so was trying it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, please upvote and/or accept it, so other SO users know that this question has been answered.